# "typedef iterator<const value_type> const_iterator;" results in: "error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers"

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, containers, constants

I want to create a vector from Zero and this requires creating an iterator class as well, but I have this problem when I want to set a const iterator
That's my vector

```
template < class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T> > class vector {
        public:
            typedef T                                               value_type;
            typedef Alloc                                           allocator_type;
            typedef T*                                              pointer;
            typedef T const *                                       const_pointer;
            typedef T&                                              reference;
            typedef T const &                                       const_reference;
            typedef iterator<value_type>                            iterator;
            typedef iterator<const value_type>                      const_iterator;
            typedef reverse_iterator<iterator>                      reverse_iterator;
            // typedef reverse_iterator<const_iterator>                const_reverse_iterator;
            typedef typename allocator_type::size_type              size_type;
            typedef typename allocator_type::difference_type        difference_type;
```

and that's my iterator class

```
template <class T> class iterator {
        protected:
            T* m_ptr;
        public:
            typedef T                   value_type;
            typedef value_type*         pointer;
            typedef value_type* const   const_pointer;
            typedef value_type&         reference;
            typedef value_type const & const_reference;
            typedef std::ptrdiff_t           difference_type;

            iterator() : m_ptr(nullptr) {}
            iterator(pointer ptr) : m_ptr(ptr) {}
            iterator(const iterator &iter) {m_ptr = iter.m_ptr;}
```

The error:

```
./vector.hpp:17:29: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
            typedef iterator<const value_type>                      const_iterator;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Ask yourself what thing named `iterator` the compiler will find first when looking for that name from the declaration in the error message and whether that is really the entity you want to refer to. Also, a vector is a contiguous container and so can just use pointers as iterators. That simplifies the design a lot.

Comment: is this the complete error message? I'd expect an error already on the line above https://godbolt.org/z/6jd1h68hr

Comment: Curios why you'd want to re-invent the wheel at all? Exercise? Pure curiosity of yours?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The first declaration is actually ill-formed, no diagnostic required. For example Clang and MSVC will accept it. (The rule says that lookup of the name should yield the same result when repeated in the completed class scope, which it doesn't for the first mention of `iterator`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to redefine the template to a concrete type:

```
typedef iterator<value_type>                            iterator;
```

I suggest renaming the class template to something else, like `iterator_impl`:

```cpp
template <class T> class iterator_impl {
    protected:
        T* m_ptr;
    public:
        typedef T                   value_type;
        typedef value_type*         pointer;
        typedef value_type* const   const_pointer;
        typedef value_type&         reference;
        typedef value_type const &  const_reference;
        typedef std::ptrdiff_t      difference_type;

        iterator_impl() : m_ptr(nullptr) {}
        iterator_impl(pointer ptr) : m_ptr(ptr) {}
        iterator_impl(const iterator_impl &iter) : m_ptr{iter.m_ptr} {}
};
```

Then this'll work:

```cpp
template < class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T> > class vector {
    public:
        typedef T                                         value_type;
        typedef Alloc                                     allocator_type;
        typedef T*                                        pointer;
        typedef T const *                                 const_pointer;
        typedef T&                                        reference;
        typedef T const &                                 const_reference;
        typedef iterator_impl<value_type>                 iterator;
        typedef iterator_impl<const value_type>           const_iterator;
        typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator>           reverse_iterator;
        // typedef reverse_iterator<const_iterator>       const_reverse_iterator;
        typedef typename allocator_type::size_type        size_type;
        typedef typename allocator_type::difference_type  difference_type;
};
```

Comment: Ooh, I didn't notice it, Thank you so much